# Spring MVC @PathVariable List Input javax max Size validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Spring Boot- Spring MVC Project below Rest API

```
@GetMapping(value = "bulk/{speakerIds}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.MULTI_STATUS)
@Operation(summary = "Gets Speakers to a max Limit of 10")
public Map<Long, Object> getMasterClassBulk(@PathVariable List<Long> speakerIds) {

    return speakerHandler.getSpeakers(speakerIds);

}
```

Is there a way to add List Max Size validation ?
Eg: When the input list exceeds size 10, throw **404-Bad Request**

Tried below code, but it does not work.

```
@PathVariable @Size(max=10) List<Long> speakerIds
```

Comment: try annotating class with `@Validated` annotation

Comment: without validation it works??.how::  `/bulk/[1,2,3]` ?? (urlencoded: `/bulk/%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D` ;)

Comment: The count of path variables cannot be variable!(...) ...use parameters/body instead! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try anotating the class with @Validated and try this on method argument:

```
@Valid @PathVariable @Size(max=10) List<Long> speakerIds
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to add List Max Size validation ? Eg: When the input list exceeds size 10, throw 404-Bad Request

If this is your question than you can simplify it by using

```
public Map<Long, Object> getMasterClassBulk(@PathVariable List<Long> speakerIds) {
    
    if(speakerIds.size()>10)
      throw new BadRequestException("Length too long");

    return speakerHandler.getSpeakers(speakerIds);

}
```

Create BadRequestException class like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)  
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException   
{  
public BadRequestException(String message)   
{  
super(message);  
}  
}
```